# React Log Running Twice

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React and was wondering why console.log() was executing twice when I run my app?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';
import useResults from '../hooks/useResults';
import ResultsList from '../components/ResultsList';

const SearchScreen = () => {
    const [ term, setTerm ] = useState( '' ),
        [ searchApi, results, errorMessage ] = useResults();

    const filterResultsByPrice = ( price ) => {
        return results.filter( result => {
            return result.price === price;
        } );
    }

    console.log( results[0].name ); // Is being printed twice. Why?

    return (
        <View style={ { flex: 1 } }>
            <SearchBar
                term={ term }
                onTermChange={ setTerm }
                onTermSubmit={ () => searchApi( term ) }
            />
            { errorMessage ? <Text>{ errorMessage }</Text> : null }
            <Text>We have found { results.length } results.</Text>
            <ScrollView>
                <ResultsList title="Cost Effective" results={ filterResultsByPrice( '$' ) } />
                <ResultsList title="Bit Pricier" results={ filterResultsByPrice( '$$' ) } />
                <ResultsList title="Big Spender" results={ filterResultsByPrice( '$$$' ) } />
                <ResultsList title="Price Unknown" results={ filterResultsByPrice( undefined ) } />
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create( {} );

export default SearchScreen;
```

When I view the log in Git Bash, I notice it's executed twice instead of just once, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your component re-renders twice:

1. when the state is initialized
2. when the state is updated.

Therefore your code in the component body re-executes so to say.

Comment: One thing i noticed in your code you are calling your function `filterResultsByPrice` and passing undefined to it as an argument. No need for it. If you call a function and don't pass an argument it will be undefined by default. See [this](https://javascript.info/function-basics#default-values).

Comment: Yes, I understand but the state is initialized in another component. When the state is initialized, it should be an empty array, []. But on the log, the name is printed twice. Shouldn't the log print [] the first time, and the name the second time?

Comment: Actually if it is an empty array your app should crash when the first time it is rendered. Because when you access 0th index element it is `undefined` and there is no name property on `undefined` value.

Comment: Since my app is not crashing, I can safely assume my state was already initialized in the other component, that's why the name is correctly printed twice?

Comment: Sure for 100 percent. I also assume you have some conditional rendering for this `SearchScreen` component, otherwise it would break for sure

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it really helps me a lot in understanding how React works. Answer accepted. ✅

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behavior as components can render several times. The console log is just getting executed whenever your component renders.

To execute some code only once (When the component is mounted for the first time), use useEffect hook passing the second parameter as [ ] (an empty array).

Or perhaps, you might want to print to console whenever the results change. So instead of an empty array, you can pass [results] as the second param to useEffect so that the code within useEffect gets executed whenever the `results` change and not on every render.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(results[0].name);
}, [results]);
```

Here is a good explanation if you are new to useEffect hook: [useEffect](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-explanation/)